# How to draw icebergs like the following image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, illustration

I want to draw some icebergs in Gimp or Photoshop. In Gimp I tried Path Tool, and then I tried to fill in the colors with Bucket Fill, but this gave me a very bad result. So my question is if anyone can help me, either in Photoshop or Gimp, to get started?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In Photoshop, just use the `Pen Tool` -- it sounds like you are a beginner so I'd recommend checking [out some tutorials](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-73a0a.html).

[Here is a good one that goes over creating your own shapes in Photoshop.](http://www.tutorial9.net/tutorials/photoshop-tutorials/pen-tool-basics-in-photoshop/)

To address the images you've linked, I would split that up into 5 layers. One for the background, the back mountains, their shading, the front mountains, and their shading.

Since the mountains are a single color (aside from the shading) you can use a single shape for them. Then I'd create multiple "shading" shades on top to give the mountains depth.

Comment: Just to note that everything Johannes refers to in Photoshop can be done in GIMP - nothing advanced software-wise is needed here. It's just about good judgement with colours, shades, placement, consistent light source, etc, and keeping it all organised well like Johannes describes.